# Running node_exporter with Ansible

Tags: ansible, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I start `node_exporter` like this

```
cd /exporter
```

then

```
./node_exporter &
```

I tried running `node_exporter` with Ansible using `shell` module but had no success

```
- name: Run Exporter
  become: yes
  ansible.builtin.shell: " ./node_exporter & "
  args:
    chdir: /home/netmera/exporter/
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Running in background won't work with ansible as the process will be killed as soon as the task exits. You could run this with `nohup` but that would still be a bad practice. See @U880D answer for a solution that is more in the state of the art.

Answer (score 6):

According your description you may introduce automatic installation like

```yaml
- name: Download and unpack node exporter binary to /usr/local/bin
  unarchive:
    src: "https://{{ URL}}/node_exporter-{{ NODE_EXPORTER_VERSION }}.linux-amd64.tar.gz"
    dest: "/usr/local/bin/"
    remote_src: yes
    extra_opts: [--strip-components=1]
    owner: "root"
    group: "root"
```

create a [`group`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/group_module.html) and [`user`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html) to run the `node_exporter` as a service like

```yaml
- name: Create group 'node_exporter' to run the node exporter service
  group:
    name: "node_exporter"
    state: present

- name: Create user 'node_exporter' to run the node exporter service
  user:
    name: "node_exporter"
    group: "node_exporter"
    state: present
    ...
```

a [systemd](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/tree/master/examples/systemd) [`node_exporter.service`](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/master/examples/systemd/node_exporter.service) file like

```
[Unit]
Description=Node Exporter
After=network.target
    
[Service]
User=node_exporter
Group=node_exporter
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node_exporter
     
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and roll it out via [`copy`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) or [`template`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html)_module depending on your infrastructre, environment and needs.

After that you can use the [`systemd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html)_module to manage the service.

```yaml
- name: Make sure 'node_exporter' service is started and enabled
  systemd:
    name: node_exporter
    state: started
    enabled: yes
    daemon_reload: yes
```

Furthermore it might be necessary to manage the local [`firewalld`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/firewalld_module.html) and open ports like

```yaml
- name: Do permit traffic in default zone for 'node_exporter' on port 9001/tcp
  firewalld:
    port: 9001/tcp
    permanent: yes
    state: enabled
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. Actually what i want to achive is just running the node_exporter process. When i run the "./node_exporter &" on the shell, the process starts. So i thought with the shell module i can manage to run it like so, but it seem i need a module like systemd and for it i need a .service file beforehand. I will run this playbook for the new machines, so i try to avoid creating file etc.. Is there another module to run it directly?

Comment: @İlkerDemirci, regarding your question "_Is there another module to run it directly?_", this was already answered in a comment by @Zeitounator, "_Running in background won't work with Ansible as the process will be killed as soon as the task exits. You could run this with `nohup` but that would still be a bad practice._". So in short the answer is no.