# Start a service at startup with Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, debian, systemd

I'm coming from the Docker side of things. Managing "services" is rather simple. 1 "service" = 1 container. Ensuring that a service is running at startup is easy with Ansible.

But when it comes to managing services on a Debian/Ubuntu based Linux machine, I know there's  `systemd`. But I can't find a proper Ansible module to define services and ensure that they run on startup. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very vague and does not provide much information. However, regarding

> *... I can't find a proper Ansible module to define services ...*

you may have a look into the documentation of the [`systemd`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/systemd_module.html)_module.

To

> *... ensure that they run on startup ...*

you could use something like

```yaml
- name: Make sure {{ SERVICE }} is started and enabled
  systemd:
    name: "{{ SERVICE }}"
    state: started
    enabled: true
```

To be able to start and enable a "service" via the `systemd`_module you'll need just a systemd service file.

**Further Documentation**

- [Manage services](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/service_module.html)
- [Writing basic systemd service files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15348/)

One example for creating and managing a simple service is

- [Installing and running Prometheus `node_exporter` as a service via Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70650885/6771046)

Comment: I already saw these modules, I can't create a new services with them. I can only manage existing ones.

Comment: @shellwhale, can you provide a minimal example what do mean by creating new "services" or describe your problem much more detailed?

Comment: I'm simply looking to run a binary on startup. Syncthing more precisely https://docs.syncthing.net/users/autostart.html#linux

Comment: @shellwhale, I see, it is quite similar to the already provided `node_exporter` example. And the from you mentioned `syncthing` documentation has all information which is necessary to make a "service" from.

Comment: I see thank you. I was expecting a module to add new units but it looks like copying a file is enough.