# Prometheus - How to protect 'node_exporter'

Tags: ansible, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I just used Ansible to monitor my servers with Prometheus, Grafana and Node Exporter. I have one monitoring server (Prometheus) & one webserver (Node Exporter).

I followed a tutorial for the setup. The thing is that it does not provide any information about security. For the moment any one is able to listen on the `node_exporter` port of my webserver.

I thought about `iptable` to protect my webserver from external calls on `node_exporter` port. Then I will only give access to my Promotheus server.

Is it the way to do?

Answer (score 0):

There might be mainly three options

1. Local or external firewall, as already mentioned in your question
2. Setting up an encryption proxy ([`sshified`](https://github.com/hoffie/sshified)) on your Prometheus Server, which encrypts the outgoing session over SSH to the `node_exporter` nodes
3. Setting up an encryption proxy (`stunnel`) on your Prometheus Nodes, which let you  only make an encrypted session, see [Authentication and encryption for Prometheus and its exporters](https://0x63.me/tls-between-prometheus-and-its-exporters/)

Option 3 can be easily added to the solution of [Running `node_exporter` with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70650714/running-node-exporter-with-ansible/70650885#70650885).

Option 2 is also quite simple and can be done via Ansible easily.

Option 1 can be done via Ansible modules available for (local) firewall configuration like `firewalld`.

There might be more solutions possible like [ghostunnel](https://github.com/ghostunnel/ghostunnel), ...