# How to convert a 'curl | bash' command line into an Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

Right now I am installing agents one by one on several Workstations. But I like to use Ansible with which I can automate the installation of the agents for the Workstation.

This is the command line I am trying to translate into the Ansible playbooks:

```sh
curl https://repository.rudder.io/tools/rudder-setup | bash -s setup-agent 7.3 [policy server hostname or ip]
```

Having troubles to put this together since I am still a beginner with Ansible.

Comment: Can you be more clear? It is really hard to understand what are you trying achieve, but I would suggest splitting this command to several Ansible tasks. For example download given rudder-setup script in first task and executing it in another one.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume:

1.) You have an infrastructure and therefore [build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-to-build-your-inventory) file `hosts.ini` like

```ini
[controlnode]
ctrl.example.com

[rudder_server]
pol.example.com

[rudder_clients]
wrkst1.example.com
wrkst2.example.com
wrkst3.example.com
```

2.) You like to [organize and group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) in a file `group_vars/rudder_clients/policy_server`

```yaml
---
policy_server: pol.example.com
```

3.) You don't want to do `curl {something} | sudo bash -` because of "*[Is that really a reasonably safe installation method?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/213401/)*" - therefore [the Bash installation script](https://repository.rudder.io/tools/rudder-setup) is already downloaded, reviewed and stored under `group_files/rudder_clients/rudder-setup.sh`.

---

A  minimal example playbook could look like

```yaml
- hosts: rudder_clients
  become: true
  gather_facts: false
  
  # For convenience and demonstration purpose stored here
  # instead of the corresponding group_vars file

  vars:
  
    role: 'setup-agent'
    version: '7.3'
  
  tasks:
  
  - name: Install Rudder Agent on Workstations
    script: rudder-setup.sh {{ role }} {{ version }} {{ policy_server }}
    args:
      creates: /opt/rudder-setup.sh
      executable: /bin/bash
```

**Further Documentation**

- [`script` module – Runs a local script on a remote node after transferring it](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html)
- [Rudder Documentation :: Quick installation](https://docs.rudder.io/reference/7.3/installation/quick_install.html)

  > *This is a bit like the insecure `curl | sh`, this is because it is intended for quick testing. Please read the full installation section if you want the complete procedure.*

Please take note that this needs to be adjusted to your needs, **it is not considered as a good practice** and you may also have a look into

- [Rudder: Continuous Auditing & Configuration](https://github.com/Normation/rudder)
- [Rudder agent support utility repository](https://github.com/Normation/rudder-agent)

---

**How to proceed further?**

Since the above (script)

> *... will setup Rudder repository on your system and the use the package manager to install rudder ... in latest version ...*

you probably want to convert `rudder-setup.sh` script parts into an Ansible playbook at all instead of just executing it. For the agent part it looks achievable within a day and to do so, start from `line 846` and `# Setup rudder agent #` first.

By doing this you will take advantage of all available Ansible capabilities and modules like [Conditionals based on `ansible_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditionals-based-on-ansible-facts), `package_facts`, `yum_repository`, `yum`, `service`, `systemctl` etc., and many more. It would end up in something simple like shown in [Running `node_exporter` with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70650885/6771046).

In order to proceed further you might find out during your research that there is already a [Rudder Ansible Collection](https://github.com/Normation/rudder-ansible) and a [role to install `rudder_agent`](https://github.com/Normation/rudder-ansible/tree/master/roles/rudder_agent). So you may either use it as it is or adopt from there.