# Execute bash script on remote host

Tags: bash, ansible, execute

I write playbook
Copy my bash script to remote host & run it, but on second task i have  problem:

```
TASK [Activate bash script] *****************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access 'sh'\nSearched in:\n\t/home/ansible/ansible/playbooks/files/sh\n\t/home/ansible/ansible/playbooks/sh\n\t/home/ansible/ansible/playbooks/files/sh\n\t/home/ansible/ansible/playbooks/sh on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}
```

My playbook:

```
---
- name: install sh script - db cleaner
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: root
    ansible_become_password: password
    ansible_become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Install bash script
    raw: wget "http://ip/clear_db_duplo.sh" -O /mnt/azimuth-data/temp/clear_db_duplo.sh && chmod +x /mnt/azimuth-data/temp/clear_db_duplo.sh

  - name: Activate bash script
    become: yes
    script: sh /mnt/azimuth-data/temp/clear_db_duplo.sh
```

On local use after copy this script are executed

try to use

```
command:
script:
raw:
```

Comment: Not an explanation for your error, but: Why are you trying to run your script with `sh`, when you say that you want to run it as `bash`?

Comment: Remove the `sh`. Ansible searches for scripts in the cwd which has no `sh`. Check the docs https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html#examples if you really need to override your default shell, which I doubt.

Comment: To emphasize what user1934428 said above: sh is not bash. Even when they're linked together and point to the same executable, bash disables some of its features when called under the name `sh` -- and on many common distros (including Alpine, Debian, and Ubuntu), sh isn't linked to bash at all in the first place but instead points to a more minimal shell like ash or dash.

Comment: Anyhow -- can you successfully run `sudo -U root sh /mnt/azimuth-data/temp/clear_db_duplo.sh` on the target host _without_ involving ansible? Make sure it works at all before trying to make it work with a specific tool. (And whether or not it works, edit that success or failure into the question itself).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```yaml
  tasks:
  - name: Download bash script
    command: wget "http://ip/clear_db_duplo.sh" -O /mnt/azimuth-data/temp/clear_db_duplo.sh 

  - name: Set permissions
    command: chmod +x /mnt/azimuth-data/temp/clear_db_duplo.sh

  - name: Activate bash script
    become: yes
    command: /mnt/azimuth-data/temp/clear_db_duplo.sh
```

Comment: idont know why its not work later.. but its work now
---
- name: install sh script - db cleaner
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: root
    ansible_become_password: 2360087
    ansible_become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Install bash script
    raw: wget "http://10.119.101.50/clear_db_duplo.sh" -O /mnt/azimuth-data/temp/clear_db_duplo.sh && chmod +x /mnt/azimuth-data/temp/clear_db_duplo.sh
   - name: Activate bash script
    become: yes
    raw: sh /mnt/azimuth-data/temp/clear_db_duplo.sh
    ignore_errors: True

Answer (score 0):

In order to [download files from HTTP, HTTPS, or FTP to node, use `get_url` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html).

```yaml
---
- name: Install sh script - db cleaner
  hosts: all
  become: trrue
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    IP: 192.0.2.1
    SCRIPT: clear_db_duplo.sh

  tasks:

  - name: Install script
    ansible.builtin.get_url:
      url: "http://{{ IP }}/{{ SCRIPT }}"
      dest: /mnt/azimuth-data/temp/
      mode: '0700'
```

Please take note that [`script` module – Runs a local script on a Remote Node after transferring it](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html) from the Control Node. Therefore the whole case could probably done in a single `script` task, if the the script becomes provided on the Control Nodes project file directory. See in example [How to convert a `curl | bash` command line into an Ansible playbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76487674/6771046)