# Ansible Playbook doesn't rename a directory when using a wildcard

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to download Node Exporter archive from the web and untar it on a destination machine. Everything goes fine until I try to rename directory:

```yaml
    - name: Download and unarchive Node Exporter
      ansible.builtin.unarchive:
        src: https://github.com/n_e/node_exporter-1.6.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
        dest: /usr/local/bin
        remote_src: yes
    - name: Rename Node Exporter directory
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
        find /usr/local/bin/ -depth -type d -name 'node_exporter*' -exec mv {} node_exporter \;
    - name: Change owner of node_exporter directory
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: /usr/local/bin/node_exporter
        state: directory
        recurse: true
        owner: nodex
        group: nodex
```

After the playbook finishes, I end up with two directories in the folder, of which the renamed one is empty:

```
/usr/local/bin$ ls node_exporter*
node_exporter:

node_exporter-1.6.1.linux-amd64:
LICENSE  NOTICE  node_exporter
```

I was trying to rename the directory with `mv` command, but it didn't work either.

What I want to achieve, is having the `LICENSE  NOTICE  node_exporter` files located in `/usr/local/bin/node_exporter` directory.

What is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: Maybe you can take advantage from [Running node_exporter with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70650885/6771046). By using the there shown approach, no additional tasks for move and setting ownership are necessary. Means, just use `extra_opts: [--strip-components=1] owner: "nodeex" group: "nodeex" ` in your `unarchive` tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making this a bit too complicated IMO and using too much shell when solutions exist with modules. `tar` (behind `unarchive`) has an option to strip components from the extracted path names. Just use it and extract your files directly in the directory you want. Example `test.yml` using my tmp dir and the official prometheus node_exporter release for test.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    app_dest_dir: /tmp/node_exporter

  tasks:
    - name: Make sure app dir exists
      file:
        path: "{{ app_dest_dir }}"
        state: directory

    - name: Download and unarchive Node Exporter stripping first dir in archive
      ansible.builtin.unarchive:
        src: https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/releases/download/v1.6.1/node_exporter-1.6.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
        dest: "{{ app_dest_dir }}"
        remote_src: true
        extra_opts:
          - "--strip-component=1"
```

Testing the above gives:

```
$ # show dest dir does not exist before test

$ ls /tmp/node_exporter
ls: cannot access '/tmp/node_exporter': No such file or directory

$ # Run the playbook

$ ansible-playbook test.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Make sure app dir exists] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Download and unarchive Node Exporter stripping first dir in archive] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


$ # Check directory exist and content is what's expected

$ ls /tmp/node_exporter/
LICENSE  node_exporter  NOTICE
```

Answer (score -1):

This piece seems to solve the problem with success:

```yaml
    - name: Rename Node Exporter directory
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
        find /usr/local/bin/ -depth -type d -name 'node_exporter*' -exec rsync -a {}/ /usr/local/bin/node_exporter/ \;
    - name: Remove unpacked directory
      ansible.builtin.shell: |
        find /usr/local/bin/ -depth -type d -name 'node_exporter-*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
    - name: Change owner of node_exporter directory
      ansible.builtin.file:
        path: /usr/local/bin/node_exporter
        state: directory
        recurse: true
        owner: nodex
        group: nodex
```

Contents of both directories has to be aligned with `rsync` and then, in an additional task, the unarchived directory can be located with `find` and removed.